# Move Running Applications from Taskbar to System Tray

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, notification-area

Hey there everybody so I have an apparently rare question.

I wish to take running programs and hide their icon from my taskbar while keeping them open on *one desktop.* For example; say I have my steam friends list open. Now there's a steam icon in the taskbar. At the same time I would like to see Discord as well, that's another icon open in the taskbar. I also want to run VirtualBox and keep an eye on the system I'm running, there's another icon. Now I lets say I need to start work, well now I have all my work related icons in the taskbar as well as steam and discord and the VM. For me, its a little cluttered and annoying. I figure, since I'm passively using some programs, it wouldn't harm their functionality to just hide those icons (or just move them to the notification area/system tray, whatever Microsoft calls it nowadays) so that my taskbar is a bit more neat and focused. Now the immediate response I've seen about this topic is along the lines of,

"Just create a virtual desktop and bam no more unnecessary taskbar clutter."

The issue with that is I want to keep those passive programs open and visible to me. Ergo the virtual desktop option is out.

In my searches I stumbled upon a [thread](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/171700-hide-delete-program-icon-taskbar-2.html) on the good ol' TenForums which addressed this exact issue! I thought it a miracle, but the programs they suggest are outdated and don't work.

There are other programs as well that have in the past attempted to solve this issue, such as: OuttaSight, Moo0 Always on Top, Tray it!, eXtrabuttons, and a lot more. The problem with these programs is that they are old (usually 5+ years), unsupported, and incompatible with W10.

So, does anyone have any suggestions for this? Is there a program I'm not seeing or a keyword I'm missing? Am I just stupid for wanting this? I'm moreso amazed that this is apparently a fringe topic and hasn't had a solid answer in the past 5 years.

Any ideas or help is appreciated!

Comment: If you have 2 monitors, you can tell windows to only show programs that are open on that window which would already remove clutter. That said, I use Actual Tools Window Manager (paid) which has a huge load of tools, including the option to remove a taskbar button and even minimize to desktop or system tray, which is essentially what you want. The program is open and while open, you switch to it by clicking the window, or when minimized, access it through an icon in the systemtray.

Comment: Aha! This is almost exactly what I am looking for. I managed to get it to hide the programs I wanted! The downside to this program though is that it's a bit convoluted and for my purposes over-engineered as I only am using it for one of many features.

Regardless, this is great! Thank you so much.

Comment: Actual Window Manager is their total suite. If you find the controls you are looking for, get their slimmed version with just that section. Its cheaper too, but once you've seen what the entire package can do, honeslt,y its so much worth to just get the full package. I use it in conjunction with TidyTabs to group windows to one window so to speak. I used to use Actual Tools's virtual desktops before for the same purpose, which mostly does the same thing, except that TidyTabs gives me this small bar above the program so I can quickly switch between the groups.